# Wi-Fi speed slows down when lid is closed

Tags: networking, wireless, hdmi

I bought a DELL monitor for my DELL ubuntu laptop. 
I noticed my wifi connection was much slower than usual, so I spent some time diagnosing my network settings and upgrading the kernel. At the end, it turned out that my connection was slow only when my laptop was connected to my new monitor using HDMI. I also noticed that if the lid is open,there are no wifi problems. This makes me think the issue is not with the HDMI cable itself, but should be a software one.

Please, can anyone point me which settings should I alter in order to fix this issue?

UPDATE: I tried another monitor with another cable and the issue persists. Therefore, it must be connected to the antena in the lid, I guess, as suggested in the comments. Still no idea how to fix it, though, except for just leaving it open :=)

Thanks

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the HDMI and all to do with the lid's position. Antennae are often in the lid.

Comment: does this mean there is nothing I can do? :)

Comment: It's very hard to test this hypothesis - excluding the external monitor - without a very complex remote access and measurements (and the remote access itself would probably skew the results). But going by what is and what isn't being reported I'm confident in saying the monitor isn't a factor. There are reported cases of interference with WiFi but only from certain USB3.0 ports/hubs when mounted in close proximity of the antenna. Also a few issues with Bluetooth coexistence, but nothing regarding HDMI or monitors.

Comment: I can confirm it is not the monitor or the cable, as I tried it with another HDMI cable on another monior and the issue continues. And you are right it is something regarding the antena, as I tried with my lid half-open and the result were inbetween .. better than closed, but worse than open.

Comment: Some laptops have two antennae wires and let you pick #1 or #2 for best reception. Another consideration although probably impractical, is propping up front to change angle. Best is to not close lid and use screen dimming or close lid and use ethernet which is faster anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Wifi antennas are usually present on the bezels of your laptop screen. So when your screen is open, the antennas are in the upright position making it the most optimal way for receiving wifi signals. On closing your laptop screen, your antennas are in a flat horizontal position making them inefficient to receive signals, thereby lowering your wifi speed.

I can give you 3 solutions for solving this problem:

1. Leave the laptop screen open.
2. Close the laptop screen and lean your laptop against a wall or any other object such that your antennas remain in a vertically upright position.
3. Use an external USB Wifi dongle and keep it oriented in the best position.