# WIFI Connection breaks down when connecting to HDMI

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, hdmi, intel

I have switched from Windows to Xubuntu a couple of weeks ago. Most things work so far. However, if I connect my laptop to HDMI the download rate sinks to zero and my Internet connection vanishes. The second I disconnect the HDMI cable the connection re-establishes and everything works as usual.

I have an Acer Travelmate 5742, an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560, my wireless interface is:

description: Wireless interface
product: BCM43225 802.11b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries

I have a proprietary driver for my WIFI. Furthermore, I had to make some adjustments to be able to use brightness control:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        Option      "TearFree"   "true"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Can anything of my adjustments cause these problems?? I switched to VGA  (which works perfectly) but I do not intend to stay this way…

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Same problem (title of question wrong) but no answers posted: [Wi-Fi speed slows down when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146876/wi-fi-speed-slows-down-when-lid-is-closed)

Comment: I would try to exchange the HDMI cable. If that is not the case check the wifi antenna position. Most laptops have them in the lid. Make the lid open apart from the HDMI cable.

Comment: I have tried to let it open when the HDMI cable is connected and yes it is much faster, but not as fast as without HDMI. My WIFI module is at the bottom of my laptop and under Windows I never encountered such problems. Is there anything I can do????

Comment: Also it does not make sense since with VGA anything is completely normal...

Comment: any one....????

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the problem appears to be, at least in my case, power related. I've been looking around for a while to try and find a solution, but I'm not sure there is one. Laptops just don't have enough power to drive external monitors, plus bluetooth and other devices. Brand new 2022 MBP, everything works great until it's connected to an external monitor. Then, bluetooth flakes, wifi drops, etc, but it seems like trying to use bluetooth is what kills it.

Up to this point, I've just been buying only peripherals that are dual mode, so when it's plugged in I can use a dongle. That seems to work OK for me most of the time, though using a dongle with my keyboard was still flaky. Had to go hard wired with that one.